# Azure-Data-Explorer: Recently increased offline rate in dev SKUs?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

We are experiencing an increase in transient errors (cluster going offline multiple times a day, databases suddenly seem to disappear, blob ingestion fails with BadRequest_InvalidBlob: BadRequest_EmptyBlob) with SKU Dev(No SLA)_Standard_E2a_v4.

We are aware there is no SLA, but currently this makes developing quite hard, and selling ADX to management is also not easy since the outage right now happened during a sprint-review presentation.

Are we alone with this issue, or is this a known, time-limited, problem?
[ADX Service multiple downtimes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAdCD.png)

Comment: What is your the cluster name?

Comment: I am not at liberty to disclose this information publicly, but will follow Yoni's advice to file a support request.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, there's no SLA on Dev SKU. Yet, quoting Yoni's important comment below: "For any issues that aren't a result of an increase in the workload running against the cluster, I would strongly recommend you open a support ticket for the resource. Downtimes measured in hours are not expected regardless of the fact this is the Dev SKU."

Comment: We do understand that. I, however, find it difficult recommending this technology to my clients if their development workflow is halted once a week for a full day with multiple up and downtimes that last 4 hours or more.

Comment: for any issues that aren't a result of an increase in the workload running against the cluster, i would strongly recommend you open a support ticket for the resource. downtimes measured in hours are not expected regardless of the fact this is the Dev SKU.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up, Yoni. After Slavik N's message we were under the impression that we were not entitled to any support at all, and that multi-hour outages for DEV SKUs are the norm. We will file a support request.

Comment: This is correct. I'll update my answer to avoid confusion.